# Get count of specific instances in an inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

I have three tables: users, lists and tasks.

The list table has user_id as a foreign key. The tasks table has list_id as a foreign key and user_id as a field.

I'm using following SQL statement to display user lists and number of completed tasks:

```
SELECT
    list.list_id,
    list_name,
    list_time_created,
    COUNT( task.task_id ) AS numberofTasks,
    COUNT( CASE WHEN task.task_completed=1 THEN 1 END) AS numberofCompletedTasks
FROM list
INNER JOIN task
    ON list.user_id = ':user_id' AND list.list_id = task.list_id
GROUP BY list_name
```

The full table designs are these:

list

- list_id
- list_name
- user_id FK

task

- task_id
- task_name
- task_completed
- user_id
- list_id FK

It does not work. How can I modify this statement to get all lists from a user (even if list doesn't contain a task) and to get number of tasks (total and completed) if there are any?

Comment: Most times you need a GROUP BY clause when you are doing COUNTS ; in this case, since you want to count per list, you need to add 'GROUP BY list_id, list_name, list_time_created' instead of the LIMIT

Comment: Edit your question and show sample data and desired results.

Comment: maybe you want a LEFT JOIN instead of an INNER JOIN?

Comment: Left join doesn't work since it gives all records in this example

Comment: If you post your schemas (use `DESCRIBE TABLE tablename` on each table and post results) it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is that you're only checking for the user_id in the list table. You need to make sure you get the proper user_id in the task table as well. One way to do so is by joining the tables on that condition, and then checking for the specific user in the where clause.

Secondly, if you want to see lists regardless of whether or not it has tasks, you should use an outer join. If you do that, I recommend modifying your aggregate functions to handle null values. Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
  l.list_id, l.list_name, l.list_time_created, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN t.task_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS numberOfTasks,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.task_completed IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE t.task_completed END) AS numberOfCompletedTasks
FROM list l
LEFT JOIN task t ON l.list_id = t.list_id AND l.user_id = t.user_id
WHERE l.user_id = 1
GROUP BY l.list_id;
```

This will select your columns, count all non-null instances of task_id, all instances where task_completed is 1 for each list_id. This will show all list_ids, so if it has no tasks we will see counts of 0. There is no need to do additional grouping by user_id here since you are querying for a specific user.

Since task_completed is either 0 or 1, using the SUM aggregate function will effectively give you the count of completed tasks. I used a check though to sum with 0 for null instances.

This worked out in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f7335/7) for me, let me know if it causes problems for you.

**EDIT**

If I can comment on your table design, I would recommend removing user_id from one of the tables. There is no need to have it in both. Say you remove user_id from the task table. I can go from task->list to get the user_id. If I have it in both, they may be inconsistent. However, this is just a comment. I don't know your whole situation, changing your design might not be a possibility or maybe you have a reason for it.

Comment: Works like a charm and you're right about duplicate user_id fields. Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Just found out after testing that this statement returns 1 even if there is no tasks in the list although it returns corrrect number of tasks in the list if that number is > 0. It's pretty confusing and i can't find the cause.

Comment: @mcbuckets the SQL Fiddle worked for me. Are you positive there are no tasks?

Comment: The third insertion in the list makes fiddle inaccurate for this example because one list can have only one user_id and i forgot to mention this. I'm kinda new to all this so i'm sorry for the mess. Fiddle would be acccurate if it didn't show number of tasks is 1 for list without tasks. That can be seen in fiddle. For fourth list there is no tasks inserted and it shows there is one.

Comment: If you can build a more accurate Fiddle (if time permits) link it here and I will take a look.

Comment: This one does the trick with respect of constraint (one list can be created and edited only by one user) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8e69/3

Answer (score -1):

Use `left join`, which shows your list even if there is no record available in task.